# Confusion with elementary definitions of conformal maps

Tags: complex-analysis, definition, proof-explanation, analytic-functions

I am having the following trouble with definitions I have copied down below regarding conformal mapping from John B. Connway's *Functions of One Complex Variable I*. I find a number of confusions in the definitions.

> **Def 1:** A *smooth path* in a region (open connected subset) $G \subseteq \Bbb C$  is a continuous function $\gamma: [a,b] \rightarrow G$ for some closed interval $[a,b]$ in $\Bbb R$ where $\gamma'(t)$ exists for each $t \in [a,b]$ and $\gamma'(t)$ is continuous on $[a,b]$.
>
> **Def 2:** Suppose $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ are two smooth paths in $G$ where $\gamma_1(t_1) = \gamma_2(t_2) = z_0$ and that $\gamma_1'(t_1) \not= 0 $ and $\gamma_2'(t_2) \not= 0$. *The angle between the paths* $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ at $z_0$ is given by 
>   $$ \arg \gamma_2'(t_2) - \arg \gamma_1'(t_1) $$
>
> **Def 3:** A map $f: U \rightarrow \Bbb C$ is *conformal* at $z_0 \in G$ if angles is preserved and the limit, 
>   $$ \lim _{z \rightarrow z_0} \frac{|f(z) - f(a)|}{|z-a|}$$
>   exists. It is *angle preserving*, if, given two smooth paths $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ which intersect at $z_0 = \gamma_1(t_1) = \gamma_2(t_2)$, with nonzero derivatives at the point, 
>   $$ \arg ( f \circ \gamma_2)'(t_2) - \arg ( f \circ \gamma_1)'(t_1) = \arg \gamma_2'(t_2) - \arg \gamma_2 '(t_2). $$

I have questions regarding just these three definitions.

1. **How does Def 2. make clear of the problem of the ambiguity in angle?** If we define $\arg z$ for $z \in \mathbb{C}$ to be in range $( - \pi, \pi] $ then we may have the following possible scenario, 
   $$\arg z_1 - \arg z_2 = ( - \pi/2) - \pi = -\frac{3\pi}{2} $$
   $$ \arg z_3 - \arg z_4 = \pi - (\pi/2) = \frac{\pi}{2} $$ 
   Then in terms of our usual notion, the above angles are the same but we cannot place equality sign. *So I believe we should add$\pmod {2 \pi}$ to modify Def 2 (?)*
2. **For Def 3. what kind of set should $U$ be?** If $U$ does not contain any open connected $G$, it may be the case that $f \circ \gamma_1$ is not even well-defined, for a given smooth path $\gamma_1$. Hence, for any point $z_0 \in U$, $f$ satisfies the condition for conformality vacuously? Thus, *I believe $U$ should at least be an open set.*
3. **For Def 3. is it not implied that $f$ satisfies some additional properties?** By Def 2, we talk about "angle between the paths" *when* we have smooth paths. So for Def 3, **is it required that $f \circ \gamma_1 : G \to \Bbb C$ and $f \circ \gamma_2: G \to \Bbb C$ to be smooth paths (?)** Or does the existence of the limit guarantee that these compositions are smooth paths? In fact **I do not understand the meaning of the condition of limit**, all I can see is it guarantees the continuity of $f$ - but does it imply it is analytic (continuously differentiable on the open set $U$).

I hope I am not missing something trivial. Thanks.

Comment: I can't believe it's been 5 years and this question didn't even get a comment?!!? Do you still have these ambiguities? I know the answer to some of these questions but I too have some things that I don't understand and I wanted to write a similar question. Lmk if you still need help with this.